# seam-faces 3 makes JBoss7.1.3 undeployed failed

Tags: jboss7.x, seam3

Does anyone encountered the problem I specified above? I tried it on several web projects and produced the same result whenever I add dependency to seam-faces and deploy the app in JBoss and undeploy the app it doesn't get undeploy. What's weird is that there is no relevant log at all. It doesn't get remove in the admin console but when I access the app url it generates:

```
HTTP Status 503 - This application is not currently available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve this issue in JBoss7.1.3 but what worked is updating to JBoss7.2.